# readonly radio buttons until the form is completely loaded

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsOfficial, true, new { @class = "col-md-3" }) xxx </label>
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsOfficial, false, new { @class = "col-md-3" }) yyy </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        </div>
</div>
```

I have two radio buttons.

I want these radio buttons to be readonly until the form is completely loaded.

When the full form is loaded, the user can select the buttons

How do I do this?

Comment: Disable them by default, then enable them in `window.onload`.

Comment: please code....

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. Show your attempt, and we will gladly help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="row">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsOfficial, true, new { @class = "col-md-3", disabled = "disabled" }) xxx </label>
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsOfficial, false, new { @class = "col-md-3", disabled = "disabled" }) yyy </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        </div>
</div>




    <script>
$(function() {
   $('[name=IsOfficial]').prop("disabled",false);
});
</script>
```